# How to create a form with option to add additional combo boxes?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, combobox

I am working on a fairly basic database for my work of various companies in the region and I'm not really experienced in Microsoft Access. I'm trying to make a form where the user can add additional fields such as a combo box to the form.

Example: They enter the company name and then select the province and then the city, but that company also operates in other cities in a different province.

How would I create something like this? Or am I going all wrong about this?

Currently I have a dual multi-select combo box, in which the user can select multiple provinces and cities.

**Current Form**
[image: Current Form]

**Companies Table**
[image: Companies Table]

**Cities Table**
[image: Cities Table]

**Provinces Table**
[image: Provinces Table]

**Relationships**
[image: Relationships]

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll need to include some sort of [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help get up votes and a faster resolution to your question.

Comment: Going about it all wrong. Normalize data structure. Avoid multi-value fields. Have another related table tblCompaniesCities. There is no need to save province into both tblProvCity (note different spelling from tblPorvCity) and tblCompanies. Save ID's of tblCities and tblCompanies into tblCompaniesCities. The associated province can be retrieved in queries that join tables. Then surely there are multiple employees associated with a company location.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I sort of had that earlier, but I'm still confused about one thing. In the able I'm supposed to have the company assigned to the city. How can I have the Companies and Cities in the same table if there are no companies in it. The idea is to have a database where Users are able to add new companies that might start up. Again I apologize if this is completely impossible to achieve, but I have very slight idea of what I'm doing here.